# What's difference among spark.shuffle.io.threads

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to learn difference among below thread configurations

```
spark.shuffle.io.serverThreads 
spark.shuffle.io.clientThreads 
spark.shuffle.io.threads 

spark.rpc.io.serverThreads
spark.rpc.io.clientThreads
spark.rpc.io.threads
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are these configs (still) legit? I don't see them in the Spark3 configuration doc (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html). :/

Where can I find more about these configs? Like where to put them, their default values, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

These configuration parameters are related to Spark's shuffle and RPC mechanisms. Shuffle is the process of redistributing data across partitions during certain operations, while RPC (Remote Procedure Call) is a communication method used within Spark components/services.

The `spark.shuffle.io.serverThreads`, `spark.shuffle.io.clientThreads`, and `spark.shuffle.io.threads` configurations control the number of threads that are used for the shuffle service.

- `spark.shuffle.io.server`: Threads specifies the number of threads that
  are used by the shuffle servers to handle incoming requests.
- `spark.shuffle.io.clientThreads`: specifies the number of threads that
  are used by the shuffle clients to send requests to the shuffle
  servers.
- `spark.shuffle.io.threads`: specifies the total number of
  threads that are used by the shuffle service. This value is the sum
  of spark.shuffle.io.serverThreads and spark.shuffle.io.clientThreads.

The `spark.rpc.io.serverThreads`, `spark.rpc.io.clientThreads`, and `spark.rpc.io.threads` configurations control the number of threads that are used for the Spark RPC service. The RPC service is used for communication between the different components of a Spark job, such as the driver and the executors.

- `spark.rpc.io.server`: Threads specifies the number of threads that are used by the RPC servers to handle incoming requests.
- `spark.rpc.io.client`: Threads specifies the number of threads that are used by the RPC clients to send requests to the RPC servers.
- `spark.rpc.io.threads`: specifies the total number of threads that are used by the RPC service. This value is the sum of spark.rpc.io.serverThreads and spark.rpc.io.clientThreads.

Comment: during shuffle, which one should I increase for executors to fetch from multiple External shuffle service?

Comment: @NebiMAydin try spark.shuffle.io.clientThreads. I am not sure how you can have multiple external shuffle services though. It is one per cluster as far as I know. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Shuffle service runs on every node in a cluster.

Comment: I only see 125 `shuffle-client` in each executor thread dump even though I set the `spark.shuffle.io.clientThreads` to 800 is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the properties `spark.shuffle.io.clientThreads` and `spark.shuffle.io.serverThreads` do not exist in Spark 3.x and above:

```
$ git checkout  v3.0.0                                                                                                  
HEAD is now at 3fdfce3... Preparing Spark release v3.0.0-rc3
$ grep -r spark.shuffle.io.serverThreads
$ grep -r spark.shuffle.io.clientThreads
```